# how to map property with array of object inside in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I'm just trying to return my array completely using map, before I will start my next function. But I am receiving incomplete array when consoling it

This is my example array:

```
data = [{
        "a": 1,
        "b": 5,
        "c": 9,
        "d": 1,
        "e": 4,
        "f": 44,
        "g": 23,
        "h": 12,
        "i": 22,
        "j": 23,
        "k": [{
            "a": 1,
            "b": 5,
            "c": 9,
            "d": 1
        }, {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 5,
            "c": 9,
            "d": 1
        }]
    },
    {
        "a": 2,
        "b": 6,
        "c": 10,
        "d": 1,
        "e": 4,
        "f": 44,
        "g": 23,
        "h": 12,
        "i": 22,
        "j": 23,
        "k": [{
            "a": 1,
            "b": 5,
            "c": 9,
            "d": 1
        }, {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 5,
            "c": 9,
            "d": 1
        }]
    },
    {
        "a": 3,
        "b": 7,
        "c": 11,
        "d": 1,
        "e": 4,
        "f": 44,
        "g": 23,
        "h": 12,
        "i": 22,
        "j": 23,
        "k": [{
            "a": 1,
            "b": 5,
            "c": 9,
            "d": 1
        }, {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 5,
            "c": 9,
            "d": 1
        }]
    },
    {
        "a": 4,
        "b": 8,
        "c": 12,
        "d": 1,
        "e": 4,
        "f": 44,
        "g": 23,
        "h": 12,
        "i": 22,
        "j": 23,
        "k": [{
            "a": 1,
            "b": 5,
            "c": 9,
            "d": 1
        }, {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 5,
            "c": 9,
            "d": 1
        }]
    }
]

var result = data.map(x=>({...x}));     
console.log(result);
```

this is my array looks like when I am consoling it:

```
[{
        "a": 1,
        "b": 5,
        "c": 9,
        "d": 1,
        "e": 4,
        "f": 44,
        "g": 23,
        "h": 12,
        "i": 22,
        "j": 23,
        "k": []
    },
    {
        "a": 2,
        "b": 6,
        "c": 10,
        "d": 1,
        "e": 4,
        "f": 44,
        "g": 23,
        "h": 12,
        "i": 22,
        "j": 23,
        "k": []
    },
    {
        "a": 3,
        "b": 7,
        "c": 11,
        "d": 1,
        "e": 4,
        "f": 44,
        "g": 23,
        "h": 12,
        "i": 22,
        "j": 23,
        "k": []
    },
    {
        "a": 4,
        "b": 8,
        "c": 12,
        "d": 1,
        "e": 4,
        "f": 44,
        "g": 23,
        "h": 12,
        "i": 22,
        "j": 23,
        "k": []
    }
]
```

I want my array to be complete when I am using the `.map()` function.

Answer (score 3):

Spreading is only a shallow copy - so the inner arrays won't be copied.

For a simple deep copy, use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`.

```js
const data = [{"a":1,"b":5,"c":9,"d":1,"e":4,"f":44,"g":23,"h":12,"i":22,"j":23,"k":[{"a":1,"b":5,"c":9,"d":1},{"a":1,"b":5,"c":9,"d":1}]},{"a":2,"b":6,"c":10,"d":1,"e":4,"f":44,"g":23,"h":12,"i":22,"j":23,"k":[{"a":1,"b":5,"c":9,"d":1},{"a":1,"b":5,"c":9,"d":1}]},{"a":3,"b":7,"c":11,"d":1,"e":4,"f":44,"g":23,"h":12,"i":22,"j":23,"k":[{"a":1,"b":5,"c":9,"d":1},{"a":1,"b":5,"c":9,"d":1}]},{"a":4,"b":8,"c":12,"d":1,"e":4,"f":44,"g":23,"h":12,"i":22,"j":23,"k":[{"a":1,"b":5,"c":9,"d":1},{"a":1,"b":5,"c":9,"d":1}]}];

const res = data.map(x => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x)));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

There's also the less well-supported [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) - this feature is currently in the draft stage:

```js
const data = [{"a":1,"b":5,"c":9,"d":1,"e":4,"f":44,"g":23,"h":12,"i":22,"j":23,"k":[{"a":1,"b":5,"c":9,"d":1},{"a":1,"b":5,"c":9,"d":1}]},{"a":2,"b":6,"c":10,"d":1,"e":4,"f":44,"g":23,"h":12,"i":22,"j":23,"k":[{"a":1,"b":5,"c":9,"d":1},{"a":1,"b":5,"c":9,"d":1}]},{"a":3,"b":7,"c":11,"d":1,"e":4,"f":44,"g":23,"h":12,"i":22,"j":23,"k":[{"a":1,"b":5,"c":9,"d":1},{"a":1,"b":5,"c":9,"d":1}]},{"a":4,"b":8,"c":12,"d":1,"e":4,"f":44,"g":23,"h":12,"i":22,"j":23,"k":[{"a":1,"b":5,"c":9,"d":1},{"a":1,"b":5,"c":9,"d":1}]}];

const res = data.map(x => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(x)));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: that does not answer the question. if taking JSON, a complete stringify and parsing omits mapping.

Comment: Recursive shallow copy will work faster and for objects that are not serializable. `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x))` is never advised. You can use `const clone = (items) => items.map(item => Array.isArray(item) ? clone(item) : item);`

Comment: Ok @NinaScholz I'll add that to the answer

Comment: Thanks @ritaj, I'll add that to the answer

Answer (score 0):

It is not because of map function it is because of console. The console can cut output if it is too long. If you need to see full result you can make

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Or some other code modifies nested arrays ( `data[0].k = []` ). Since you are making high level copy you will see empty array. In this case you should make deep copy of the original `data`.
  For this case you there is a very useful lib [lodash](https://lodash.com/)

So you can do this:

```
var result = _.cloneDeep(data);
```